# Streaming a binary file to Google Storage using Tornado

Tags: python, file-upload, stream, google-cloud-storage, tornado

I'm trying to stream a binary file from a client request to Google Cloud Storage through my server.

I'm using the Tornado framework to stream the data from the request to the server and Google Cloud Storage API for streaming the file to Google -`upload_from_file` method.

I'm new to Tornado and I'm using the `@stream_request_body` decorator so I can get the data from the request in chunks and upload each chunk to Google.

I've tried to open a file-like object to which I can write each chunk while uploading the 'file' itself to Google.

The problem is that I can't upload the 'file' to Google before I start writing chunks to it.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: `"The problem is that I can't upload the 'file' to Google before I start writing chunks to it."` So, start uploading **after** you write the first chunk? Or did you mean that you can't upload the file until all the chunks are written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with Google's HTTP libraries is tricky because they're designed for synchronous use. You need to put the actual upload on another thread to avoid blocking the IOLoop. You can use an `os.pipe` to communicate between the Tornado thread and the upload thread (wrap the writing end of the pipe in a PipeIOStream and the reading end in `os.fdopen`). Here's an untested sketch of a solution:

```
def prepare(self):
    r, w = os.pipe()
    self.write_pipe = tornado.iostream.PipeIOStream(w)
    # Create our "file-like object" for upload_from_file
    self.read_pipe = os.fdopen(r)
    # Create an event for the upload thread to communicate back
    # to tornado when it's done, and save a reference to our IOLoop.
    self.upload_done = tornado.locks.Event()
    self.io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    # Consider using a tornado.locks.Semaphore to limit the number of
    # threads you can create.
    self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.upload_file)
    self.thread.start()

def upload_file(self):
    google_client.upload_from_file(self.read_pipe)
    # tell the IOLoop thread we're finished
    self.io_loop.add_callback(self.upload_done.set)

async def data_received(self, chunk):
    await self.write_pipe.write(chunk)

async def put(self):  # or post()
    self.write_pipe.close()
    await self.upload_done.wait()
    self.thread.join()
    self.render("upload_done.html")
```

Alternately, you could avoid google's synchronous libraries and do everything using the underlying HTTP APIs and AsyncHTTPClient. Sorting out authentication this way is tricky but you avoid the threading mismatch. This would involve using a body_producer as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/5bb1bd04a443c4e06ccd#file-streaming-py-L56-L89)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is I tried both ways. Yours and the link you attached. Both failed on the same phase which is when I tried to read from the pipe while it's still empty. How can I avoid that? I tried to start the upload after the first chunk but it still gets an empty stream.

Comment: As I said, I haven't actually tested this. But reading from an empty pipe should block instead of returning an error. How exactly does it fail? Maybe upload_from_file can't handle a pipe for some other reason. But in any case, the version in the gist should work - there is no pipe involved there, and while I haven't tested it for uploading to GCS, I have tested it to generally forward an incoming request to another server.

Comment: I think the read is working but, on `upload_from_file` method, Google's implementation uses stream.tell() which doesn't block and instead throws "OSError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek"

Comment: Ah, I see. They never explain exactly what they need from a "file-like object". So to use `upload_from_file`, you'll need to stream the data to an actual file and then upload it from there. Or you could use the AsyncHTTPClient version.